# Security vulnerabilities in fairly simple c code

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

I'm studying for my last ever exam (yey!), and have run into a problem I have a hard time figuring out. It's an old exam question where you are supposed to find at least two vulnerabilities that can be exploited in a function which reads a ppm image file. The only issue I can identify is if cols and/or rows are given unexpected values, either too large (causing integer overflow) or negative, which leads to img->raster having an incorrect size, opening up the possibility of a heap-based buffer-overflow attack.

As far as I can reason, the unchecked malloc should not be exploitable.

```
struct image *read_ppm(FILE *fp)
{
    int version;
    int rows, cols, maxval;
    int pixBytes=0, rowBytes=0, rasterBytes;
    uint8_t *p;
    struct image *img;
    /* Read the magic number from the file */
    if ((fscanf(fp, " P%d ", &version) < 1) || (version != 6)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Read the image dimensions and color depth from the file */
    if (fscanf(fp, " %d %d %d ", &cols, &rows, &maxval) < 3) {
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Calculate some sizes */
    pixBytes = (maxval > 255) ? 6 : 3; // Bytes per pixel
    rowBytes = pixBytes * cols; // Bytes per row
    rasterBytes = rowBytes * rows; // Bytes for the whole image
    /* Allocate the image structure and initialize its fields */
    img = malloc(sizeof(*img));
    if (img == NULL) return NULL;
    img->rows = rows;
    img->cols = cols; 
    img->depth = (maxval > 255) ? 2 : 1;
    img->raster = (void*)malloc(rasterBytes);
    /* Get a pointer to the first pixel in the raster data. */
    /* It is to this pointer that all image data will be written. */
    p = img->raster;
    /* Iterate over the rows in the file */
    while (rows--) {
        /* Iterate over the columns in the file */
        cols = img->cols;
        while (cols--) {
            /* Try to read a single pixel from the file */
            if (fread(p, pixBytes, 1, fp) < 1) {
                /* If the read fails, free memory and return */
                free(img->raster);
                free(img);
                return NULL;
            }
            /* Advance the pointer to the next location to which we
            should read a single pixel. */
            p += pixBytes;
        }
    }
    /* Return the image */
    return img;
}
```

Original (the last question): http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDC90/exam/old/TDDC90%20TEN1%202009-12-22.pdf

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This puts me in mind of the (2008 winning) example from [The Underhanded C Contest](http://underhanded.xcott.com/), could be some clues there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a large file such that reading `row` and `cols` are both negatives. `rasterBytes = pixBytes * rows * cols` is *positive* so everything will be fine till `p = img->raster;`. But at this point you have two infinite loops, and the program may overwrite the heap.

Another attack is to set up `row` and `cols` such that they have different sign. You can choose either value to be `-1`, while the other is large enough to read the data you want. The allocation

```
  img->raster = (void*)malloc(rasterBytes);
```

will fail, which lead img->raster to point to NULL. Which means

```
 fread(p, pixBytes, 1, fp) < 1
```

will try to read the content of the file to kernel memory. If this code is executed in kernel mode, depending of the system (let say old unix which doesn use memory segment), then you will overwrite the content of the kernel memory with the content of the file. A kernel which doesn use memory segment rely not on segmentation faults but on page faults (a virtual address which doesnt have any real page assigned to it). The issue is that there are virtual memory designs such that the first real pages are directly assigned to the kernel pages. Ie kernel virtual address 0x0 is correspond to the real memory at 0x0 and is perfectly valid (inside the kernel).

**EDIT:** In both of those cases, the goal of the attacker is to inject the content of the input file (which is totally under his control) in a region of memory he should not have access to, while not being able to modify the function `read_ppm()`.

Comment: So basically, depending on the platform and priviledges, the unchecked malloc can actually be exploited? I guess it's not something you can do nowadays, but it's likely the expected answer since the other malloc in the code is checked.

Comment: yes but the attacker already did his job to write down the content of the file inside the heap

Comment: @Cesar I am not good in modern architecture, but we had an OS course which followed design purely based on pagination. Debugging inside the kernel was not easy, because you could just choose a number at random, start writing into it and everything runs fine.

Comment: @UmNyobe if you allocate a large piece of memory and read from file in that memory more than the file actually has `fread()` will return EOF and the code will return `NULL` it won't write beyond the buffer, how's is that considered a vulnerability

Comment: The attacker doesnt have to allocate a large piece of memory. It just need the loops to allow himto write the content of the file. When EOF occurs, ***he has already succeeded***

Comment: @UmNyobe for that to happen the allocation has to fail, you mentioned two cases, where the allocation fails, how are those different from each other and from the vulnerability OP mentioned ?

Comment: @mux read the exam of the OP. You know from the question that the values read are "unexpected". The OP tought about attacked on "img->raster having an incorrect size". None of my attacks are based on the size of the img->raster nor how much memory was succesfully allocated, but on where `p` end up being.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the fact that this allocation is not checked for success. Could result in a DoS.

```
img->raster = (void*)malloc(rasterBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If allocation fails at:

```
img->raster = (void*)malloc(rasterBytes);
```

you could be writing through some memory you didn't intend to.

And the size of that allocation is controlled by data in the very file.